# Delete Strings from an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have an Array that looks like this:

```
arr = [ 1, 5, "dog", 6 ]
```

How can I delete the String so that my output will look like this:

```
[ 1, 5, 6 ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
arr.select! { |el| el.class != String }
```

or if you want only numbers:

```
arr.select! { |el| el.is_a? Numeric }
```

Comment: `select` is semantically incorrect, it’s worth it to use `reject` here.

Answer (score 5):

The other way round would be to use *case-equal*:

```
[1, 5, "dog", 6].reject &String.method(:===)
#⇒ [1, 5, 6]
```

Comment: This is needlessly clever. `reject {|s| String === s }` is shorter, clearer, and (I'm guessing) more performant.

Comment: @Jordan, that it's shorter is a fact, subjectively, I too find it clearer, but I'm not sure about more "performant", as I've never been able to figure out what that means. Also the voting seems to cast doubt on it being "needlessly clever", and many here clearly have a need to post clever answers.

Comment: @CarySwoveland [This is what I mean by performant.](https://gist.github.com/jrunning/fe7c06ce17079d917a5d8dc7b65406c7)

Comment: @Jordan: The advantage of point-free programming is that it avoids the need to artificially invent names for things that are not relevant to the solution at hand. As we all know, naming is hard. The flip side of that is: naming things elevates their importance. But what if they really *are* unimportant? Then, they should not have names.

Comment: I am not ignorant of that advantage. Neither, however, am I ignorant of the disadvantages. How you weigh that advantage against those disadvantages is subjective, but you should nevertheless weigh them.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good opportunity to use [`Enumerable#grep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) or [`Enumerable#grep_v`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep_v):

```
[ 1, 5, "dog", 6 ].grep(Numeric)
# => [1, 5, 6]

[ 1, 5, "dog", 6 ].grep_v(String)
# => [1, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also go the opposite way and use `reject!`. It removes all the elements that matches the condition you set.

```
arr.reject! { |el| !el.is_a? Numeric }
```

This is functionally the same as

```
arr.select! { |el| el.is_a? Numeric }
```

Comment: `is_a?` or `===` is preferable to calling `.class` on something manually.

Comment: Your first example doesn't work, returns an empty array `[]`. This is because when checking the class of a regular number with `class`, it returns `Fixnum`. Whereas `is_a?` considers the ancestor classes too.